# How to perform action on tapped word in UITextView?

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and am trying to implement a method where a word tapped in a textView (called 'text' in my code) results in a performed action.

I have watched the presentation at WWDC 2013 (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/220/ - @24:05) and tried to implement the example of 'Hit Testing' in my app. However, I am receiving the error 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' from my handleTap method. Here's the code that I have so far. Be grateful for any pointers on where I'm going wrong. Thanks.

```
@IBAction func handleTap(sender: 
UITapGestureRecognizer) {

var layoutManager : NSLayoutManager
var location : CGPoint
var characterIndex : Int = 0
var fraction : CGFloat = 0.0

    layoutManager = text.layoutManager
    location = sender.location(in: text)
    characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: text.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: &fraction)

    if (characterIndex < text.textStorage.length) {
        print("tap success!")
    }
```

Comment: What's the full error message you're getting?

Comment: The full error message is: SpeechTest[] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SpeechTest.ViewController handleTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdd0f510460'

Comment: Disconnect and then reconnect your IBAction or change it to `handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)` with the underscore.

Comment: Thanks the underscore was the culprit. It was driving me nuts. Thanks again.